# Can't start SQL Server services

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, windows-10, sql-server-2014

I have 2 SQL Server instances on my PC, `MSSQLSERVER2012` and `SQLEXPRESS2014` and both of them were working properly.

But suddenly, both of them stopped and I can't run them again at all.

I get this error:

> The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion

I checked tcp/ip setting, even disabled tcp/ip of both instances.

I guessed it might be related to VIA protocol, but I can't see VIA protocol in my configuration manager.

I'll post the error log that SQL Server generates when it failed to start.

> 2017-05-17 22:24:07.77 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2012 -
>   11.0.2100.60 (X64)    Feb 10 2012 19:39:15    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation     Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 
>   (Build 9200: )
>
> 2017-05-17 22:24:07.77 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
>   2017-05-17 22:24:07.77 Server      All rights reserved. 2017-05-17
>   22:24:07.77 Server      Server process ID is 6044. 2017-05-17
>   22:24:07.77 Server      System Manufacturer: 'System manufacturer',
>   System Model: 'System Product Name'. 2017-05-17 22:24:07.77 Server
>   Authentication mode is MIXED. 2017-05-17 22:24:07.77 Server
>   Logging SQL Server messages in file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'. 2017-05-17 22:24:07.77
>   Server      The service account is 'WORKGROUP\HAMED-PC$'. This is an
>   informational message; no user action is required. 2017-05-17
>   22:24:07.77 Server
>   Registry startup parameters:
>   -d C:\Program> Files\Microsoft SQL server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
>
> -e C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
>   -l C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
>
> 2017-05-17 22:24:07.77 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:
>   -s "MSSQLSERVER" 2017-05-17 22:24:07.91 Server      SQL Server detected 1 sockets with 4 cores per socket and 4 logical processors
>   per socket, 4 total logical processors; using 4 logical processors
>   based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no
>   user action is required. 2017-05-17 22:24:07.91 Server      SQL Server
>   is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational
>   message only. No user action is required. 2017-05-17 22:24:07.91
>   Server      Detected 4087 MB of RAM. This is an informational message;
>   no user action is required. 2017-05-17 22:24:07.91
>
> Server Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
>
> 2017-05-17 22:24:07.94 Server      Error: 9694, Severity: 16, State:27.
>
> 2017-05-17 22:24:07.94 Server      Could not start Service Broker manager. Check the SQL Server error log and the Windows error log for
>   additional error messages.
>
> 2017-05-17 22:24:07.94 Server      Error: 9643, Severity: 16, State:1.
>
> 2017-05-17 22:24:07.94 Server      An error occurred in the Service
>   Broker/Database Mirroring transport manager: Error: 9694, State: 27.
>
> 2017-05-17 22:24:07.94 Server      Error: 9694, Severity: 16, State:
>   30.
>
> 2017-05-17 22:24:07.94 Server      Could not start Service Broker
>   manager. Check the SQL Server error log and the Windows error log for
>   additional error messages.
>
> 2017-05-17 22:24:07.94 Server      SQL Server Audit failed to record
>   the SERVER SHUTDOWN action.

Now I will appreciate if someone can help me start my SQL Server instances again

Comment: Open task manager, and kill existed sql server processes. Then restart service. This done the job for me..

Comment: 'WORKGROUP\HAMED-PC$' I've never used SQL with a workgroup but this may be a huge issue for windows logins. Is this user a local administrator on the SQL machine? Try starting the service with a different account if you can.

Comment: I think you have a server audit enabled with ON_FAILURE=SHUTDOWN specified so when audit failure to initiate, it shuts down your server. You should start your server in single user mode using -m to fix your audit, for detailes read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

Suddenly the services do not work anymore.. I suspect a windows update did this.
Or new group policies that not allow this account to use resources?

Two errors in the Event Viewer:

> The SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) service failed to start due to the
>   following error:  The service did not start due to a logon failure.

And

> The MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS service was unable to log on as NT
>   Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS with the currently configured password due to
>   the following error:  Logon failure: the user has not been granted the
>   requested logon type at this computer.
>
> Service: MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
>
> Domain and account: NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
>
> This service account not have the required user right "Log on as a service."
>
> User Action
>
> Assign "Log on as a service" to the service account on this
>   computer. You can use Local Security Settings (Secpol.msc) to do this.
>   If this computer is a node in a cluster, check that this user right is
>   assigned to the Cluster service account on all nodes in the cluster.
>
> If you have already assigned this user right to the service account,
>   and the user right appears to be removed, check with your domain
>   administrator to find out if a Group Policy object associated with
>   this node might be removing the right.

Hope this helps to get more information..

A solution I don't trust is removing he password of the user.
Go to Services > SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) > Properties > Log On > Remove password
But I don't think this solution is a permanent solution.

If you find anything please let me know.

==================================================

## Edit 1

We found the reason, my administrator pushed a group policy 'Log on as a service' which overruled my computer users.. and bad things started to happen.
He removed the policy and the original users returned. Everything works again after a 'gpupdate /force' in the command line.

You can find the group policy:
Start > Local Security Policy > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Right Assignment > Log on as a service. If the button 'Add User or Group' is grayed then the Admins are pushing this..

Good luck!

Jonas